# Customize Copy and paste behaviour in C#

Tags: c#

Im sure Im not the first one with the thought about Creating a customized copy and paste app.
It should be possible to save different Content to different "storage". 
Example,
1.Highlight a Text, Ctrl + C + 1, save it. 2.Highlight another Text, Ctrl + c + 2, save it. 3.Ctrl+ V + 1, Insert Text saved with Ctrl + c + 1. 4.Ctrl + v + 1, Insert Text saved With Ctrl + c + 2.

Is it technically possible to do this in c#? If Not, in what language would it Work?

I thought about Creating a service that runs in the Background  and listens for keyboard Inputs.
If i hit Ctrl+ c+ 1, the service sends a ctrl + c command, therefore copying the actual Text and then save it to a simple list or array. The otherway around with Ctrl + v + 1, etc..

Would it work like that? If not why?

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you just want to use it for your own productivity, look at AutoHotkey

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know how to search for it. I will take a look at it.

Comment: This is one of the best AutoHotkey clipboard managers out there - https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/91488-clipjump-the-ultimate-clipboard-manager-updated-091115/